# What is the integral of $\int \int \sqrt{(\sin x)^2+\cos(90-y-a)^2}$ dxdy?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to find the integral of $$\int \int \sqrt{(\sin x)^2+\cos(90-y-a)^2} dxdy $$ when $210<y<-30$ and $0<x<90$?

I integrate based on $x$ and I arrive at point where I don't know how to find the dy integral of this:

$$ \int \frac{2}{3} \left(1 - \frac{\cos 2x}{2} -\frac{\cos(2y+2a)}{2} \right)^\frac{3}{2} \left(x-\frac{\sin 2x}{4}-\frac{x\cos(2y+2a)}{2}\right) dy $$

Firstly, is the partial $dx$ integral correct?

Secondly, how to do the $dy$ integral?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Help's on its way, I'm sure. Thank you for including more context.

Comment: Thanks! But it says that this post is still closed and it's not accepting answers. So how to expect answers?

Comment: Nobody does Calculus in degrees. Angles are to be measured in radians.